# calling componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate for the same code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
componentDidUpdate()
  {
    let data ;
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/wel/')
    .then(res => {
      data = res.data;
      this.setState( {
        details: data
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {})
  }
```

**I want to use the same code for componentdidMount and for componentdidUpdate, but I don't want to repeat my code(DRY rule).ie writing the same lines of code for both the functions**

> I'm new to react :-)

Answer (score 2):

you can create a method in your component and call it in both places:

```
class Comp {
  doSomething() {  
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/wel/')
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ details: res.data });
      })
      .catch(err => {});
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.doSomething();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.doSomething();
  }
}
```